# Как узнать номер текущей строки при записи?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Пытаюсь записать XLS файл из списка словарей с помощью `openpyxl`. Удобнее всего перебирать список и использовать метод `append`, чтобы построчно добавлять информацию:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook
ws = wb.active

for element in elements:
    ws.append((element.get('name'),)
    ws.append(('Возраст:', element.get('age'))
```

Проблема в том, что я хотел бы задавать некоторым строкам стили и объединять ячейки в некоторых строках. Но для этого нужно знать номер строки. Конечно, можно было бы ввести счетчик и добавлять ему единичку после каждого выполнения `append`, но нет ли способа получше?

Можно ли как-то иначе узнать номер следующей строки?

Comment: пробовали `ws.max_row` ?

Comment: @MaxU, о, спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У объекта `worksheet` есть атрибуты `max_row` и `max_column`, в которых хранятся номера последней строки и последнего столбца - воспользуйтесь этими атрибутами.